# How to get all UNIQUE groups from contacts

Tags: android, arraylist, cursor, android-contacts

How do you get all unique groups from contacts. I am already able to get all instances of groups but I guess I have more than one account on the device so I am receiving multiple instances of the same groups like Coworkers,Coworkers,Coworkers,Coworkers,Friends, Friends.
I tried to remove the deplicate items in the ArrayList but my LinearLayout is still populated by too many instances of the same group.
Here is my code...

```
ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    final String[] GROUP_PROJECTION = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Groups._ID, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE };

Cursor gCursor = getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, GROUP_PROJECTION, null,
            null, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE);
    gCursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!gCursor.isAfterLast()) {
        int idcolumn = gCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE);
        String id = gCursor.getString(idcolumn);
        mArrayList.add(id);

LinearLayout sv = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.maingridview);
        Button iv = new Button(this);
        iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow);
        iv.setText(id);
        sv.addView(iv);


        gCursor.moveToNext();}
```

Answer (score 0):

check before adding data like,

```
if(!mArrayList.contains("resulted_data")){
    //add data
}
```